# Can't read avro in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I already have a SparkContext created and a Spark global variable. When I read ORC files, I can read them as simple as `spark.read.format("orc").load("filepath")` however, for avro I can't seem to do the same even though I try to import the jar like so:

```
    spark.conf.set("spark.jars.packages",
    "file:///projects/apps/lib/spark-avro_2.11-3.2.0.jar")
```

Error:

```
and then try to read the avro file. I get an error like so: 
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o65.load.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Failed to find data source: avro. Please find an Avro package at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html;
```

Comment: Have you check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46434255/how-to-query-datasets-in-avro-format

Comment: @Starfight The link is for spark-shell, I need it for Jupyter notebook

Comment: I see, but a contributor recommand to use `com.databricks.spark.avro` instead of `avro`, maybe interesting ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`spark.jars.packages` takes Gradle compatible coordinates:

```
spark.jars.packages  org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:2.4.2
```

Additionally, as explained in [How to load jar dependenices in IPython Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33908156/), it has to be set before JVM and `SparkSession` / `SparkContext` are initialized.

So you have to:

- Fix the settings.
- Provide these as a configuration or environment variable, before JVM is initialized.

Comment: Is it possible to destroy the current spark context that was initialized and set the spark context with the jar within jupyter?